# App will relaunch when resume from suspend status

Tags: ios

I have a simple ios game, all is well, but if I click the home to switch the game to background, wait for a while and then click the app icon, the game will relaunch. i hope it resume the saved status (status before suspending).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't happen automatically. Instead, you will need to handle the application state in your code. That includes pausing all animations, saving game state, etc.

You will also want to consider that the user can purge the app from background. So, the game should be saved prior to backgrounding.

See iOS App Programming Guide, specifically [App States and Multitasking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)